# Tracing the phases (i.e. the minima) of a potential

Tags: mathematical-optimization, physics, packages, nonlinear

Is there a Mathematica package to trace the minima of a potential as a function of some parameter, returning its *phase structure*?

Working with particle physics models (in the context of cosmology and gravitational waves), I deal with temperature-dependent potentials, of the form
$$
V(\phi,T)\ ,
$$
and would like to get their phase structure as a function of the temperature $T$. That is, I want the positions of the minima $\phi_{min}(T)$, with the identification of the different phases, as in the figure below.
[image]
Packages performing this task already exist in other languages, e.g.

- [CosmoTransitions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.4189) (python)
- [PhaseTracer](https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.02859) (C++)

Is there a Mathematica counterpart?
If not, how would you suggest to embed, say, PhaseTracer into a Mathematica module? I work with other Mathematica packages, and tracing the phases is just an intermediate step.

**NB** For a single-variable potential ($\phi$ is a scalar), this is a relatively easy task and could be even done analytically with Mathematica. The problem arises with multi-variate potentials $V(\vec{\phi},T)$, and, concerning specifically particle physics, higher-order (*loop*) corrections.

E.g. in the figure above, $\phi$ is the mean field value of a 3-scalar-fields potential.

Comment: Interesting question! I've wondered about what seems to be a mathematically similar problem, tracking maxima of a function vs a parameter (optima in evolutionary theory). Could you add an example or two of the kind of `V` functions you're interested in?

Comment: The problem is indeed a general one. A simple, `1D` toy model I am working on is
$$
V(x,T) = a (T^2 - T_0)^2 x^2 + b T x^3 + c x^4
$$

In practice, I want to apply the above to particle physics models, which could take the form
$$V(x, T) = \mu_1 x_1^2 + \mu_2 x_2^2 + \mu_{12} x_2 x_2
+ \lambda_1 x_1^4 + \lambda_2 x_2^4 + \lambda_{12} x_1^2 x_2^2,
$$
where the temperature dependence is in the parameters $\mu, \lambda, g$. These are some complicated functions that I only treat numerically (at least at the moment).